# Can I spend Stimhack credits after accessing cards?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Stimhack](http://www.netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01004) gives me 9 credits that I have to spend during a run.

Cards like [Clone Chip](http://www.netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03038) allow me to install programs during a run. I can obviously use my Stimhack credits to pay for these programs.

My question is, let's say I'd like to save my money for trashing cards in a server: **Once I've accessed and trashed cards, is it too late to then spend what I have left using Clone Chip or similar?**

My understanding is that Clone Chip (etc.) requires a paid ability window to install a program. There doesn't appear to be such a window between accessing cards and ending the run.

Am I forced to spend "spare" credits prior to accessing and guess how much I need to keep to pay for trashing, losing any that still remains?

An example to explain:

I Stimhack into a remote server. I break the only piece of ICE, leaving me with 6 Stimhack credits left. I suspect the only card in the server is a [SanSan City Grid](http://www.netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01092) which I'd like to trash (and which would cost 5 to do so). I access the card and see that it's actually a [Red Herrings](http://www.netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01091) and I trash it for one credit.

- Option A: I still have 5 credits left so I spend them to install Crypsis from my heap using Clone Chip (rather than lose the 5 credits). Then the run ends.
- Option B: My 5 credits are lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the run sequence on the back page manual, a run includes "Access Cards", so obviously, one can use the credits from stimhack to trash any accessed cards.

Now, for the Clone Chip part of the question: this is a Paid Ability, so you need a paid abilities window (the green arrow on the path charts) to use the chip.  If you look at the Revised Run structure in the FAQ (last page, [here](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf)), you will notice that the last Paid Abilities window is 4.3,  which is after passing the last piece of ICE but before any cards are accessed.  So, in your situation, you would not be able to install Crypsis and the 5 credits would be lost.